# mysql subquery returns multiple value error in update query

Tags: mysql

I ran following query and got error You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

```
update xyz x 
set x.PID = (select c.PPID 
            from 
            table1 c where c.FFID 
            in (select b.FID 
                from table1 a 
                join xyz b on a.FFID = b.fID 
                and a.FFIRD=b.PID and b.flag='4' 
                group by b.FID 
                having count(1) =1)
               ),flag='N' 
where x.FID = (select b.FID 
               from table1 a join xyz b on
               a.FFID = b.FID and 
               a.FFIRD=b.PID and b.flag='4' 
               group by b.FID 
               having count(1) =1
              )
```

I referred stackoverflow and changed my code like below. but now i am getting Subquery returns more than 1 row. please help

```
update xyz x 
set x.PID = (select abc.PPID 
            from (select c.PPID 
                  from 
                  table1 c 
                  where c.FFID 
                  in (select b.FID 
                      from 
                      table1 a join xyz b on a.FFID = b.fID 
                      and a.FFIRD=b.PID and b.flag='4' 
                      group by b.FID 
                      having count(1) =1
                      ) as abc
                      ),flag='N' 
where x.FID = (select xyz.FID 
               from (select b.FID 
                     from table1 a join xyz b on
                     a.FFID = b.FID and 
                     a.FFIRD=b.PID and b.flag='4' 
                     group by b.FID 
                     having count(1) =1)as xyz
               )
```

Comment: And what are you trying to do here?

Comment: On subquery it ask for only one row return . either do `limit 1`  or change the method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your working script, you could create a CTE and decant your data into that and then update from that or a variation along those lines:

```
 WITH YourCTE (PPID)
 AS
 (select c.PPID 
        from 
        table1 c where c.FFID 
        in (select b.FID 
            from table1 a 
            join xyz b on a.FFID = b.fID 
            and a.FFIRD=b.PID and b.flag='4' 
            group by b.FID 
            having count(1) =1)
           ),flag='N' 
 where x.FID = (select b.FID 
           from table1 a join xyz b on
           a.FFID = b.FID and 
           a.FFIRD=b.PID and b.flag='4' 
           group by b.FID 
           having count(1) =1
          )
 )
UPDATE xyz x 
SET x.PID = (SELECT PPID FROM YourCTE)
```